# Select top N items per group with conditions in the subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm adapting this **[simpler working example](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/get_top_n_each_group)** to a slightly more complex use case. Instead of joining on one foreign key I'm conducting the IF test on the successful matching of two foreign keys, and I've added in a WHERE clause in the subquery to filter out certain rows for being eligible for the rankings. However, now the rank value seems to never increment (so the IF test is always failing). The culprit is the subquery WHERE clause:

```
WHERE cand.is_pseudocandidate != 1
```

in the subquery of this query below:

```
SELECT contest_id, division_id, candidate_id, n_votes, rank, n_seats 
FROM 
    (  SELECT ccd.id, contest_id, ccd.division_id, ccd.candidate_id, n_votes, cont.n_seats, 
            @rank := IF(@current_contest = ccd.contest_id AND @current_div = ccd.division_id, @rank + 1, 1) AS rank,
            @current_contest := ccd.contest_id,
            @current_div := ccd.division_id
       FROM candidates_contests_divisions ccd 
       LEFT JOIN candidates cand ON ccd.candidate_id = cand.id
       LEFT JOIN contests cont ON ccd.contest_id = cont.id
       WHERE cand.is_pseudocandidate != 1
       ORDER BY ccd.contest_id, ccd.division_id, n_votes DESC
    ) ranked  
WHERE rank <= 3;
```

When I comment out that subquery WHERE clause, the query works as expected but of course, it is including rows which I don't want.

**How can I get this subquery WHERE clause to work without interfering with the rankings?**

[Here is the schema](https://gist.github.com/amfriedman/7aab1b8d23c87620bfe5f2add470416c) (including test data) for anyone to play with to get this working.

Comment: `WHERE cand.is_pseudocandidate != 1` will convert `LEFT JOIN candidates cand` to an INNER JOIN. But I don't know if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

you not initialize **rank** put only line between **left JOIN** and **WhERE** i think thats all

```
SELECT contest_id, division_id, candidate_id, n_votes, rank, n_seats 
FROM 
    (  SELECT ccd.id, contest_id, ccd.division_id, ccd.candidate_id, n_votes, cont.n_seats, 
            @rank := IF(@current_contest = ccd.contest_id AND @current_div = ccd.division_id, @rank + 1, 1) AS rank,
            @current_contest := ccd.contest_id,
            @current_div := ccd.division_id
       FROM candidates_contests_divisions ccd 
       LEFT JOIN candidates cand ON ccd.candidate_id = cand.id
       LEFT JOIN contests cont ON ccd.contest_id = cont.id
       CROSS JOIN ( SELECT
                      @rank := 0
                      , @current_contest := -1
                      , @current_div := -1  ) as init
       WHERE cand.is_pseudocandidate != 1
       ORDER BY ccd.contest_id, ccd.division_id, n_votes DESC
    ) ranked  
WHERE rank <= 3;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same results with this solution. Rankings are still not incrementing.

Comment: do you have the create of the tables and sample date. you can put it on http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Perhaps you should have started with that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I added a link to my schema/test data.